# divide a screen into several screens in psychtoolbox matlab

Tags: matlab, screen, psychtoolbox

I want to divide my screen into several screens and use them separately: the screen in center for playing movie and the other screens for running tasks. How can I do this in psychtoolbox 3.0 on windows 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this the most suitable way:

- windowPtr1 = Screen('OpenWindow', max(Screen('screens')), 0);
- windowPtr2 = Screen('OpenWindow', max(Screen('screens')), 0);

and use each screen with its specific windowPtr :)